# shell script - don't add quotes

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have created an npm script to run a single jest test file. To run the file I would type:

```
> npm start test:1 **/unit-test-filename.test.js
```

I want to make that even easier and type something like:

```
> jt unit-test-filename
```

So I've tried creating a bash script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
npm run test:1 **/$1.test.js
```

Unfortunately when I try running it it puts a single quote around last parameter and it make it so that npm script can't find the file. I get an output like this:

```
╰─± jt unit-test-filename                                                                                
+ npm run test:1 '**/unit-test-filename.test.js'

> cms2@0.1.2 test:1 /Users/path/to/my/current/dir
> cross-env NODE_ENV=dev node ./etc/jest1 "**/unit-test-filename.test.js"

Error!! Test file: **/unit-test-filename.test.js doesn't exist.
```

I've tried escaping the asterisk and tried a number of other things. Is this even possible with bash scripting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't have `globstar` set in a shell script.

You can enable it with `shopt -s globstar`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
shopt -s globstar
npm run test:1 **/"$1".test.js
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working now and I realized it was zsh that was making it work in my npm script so I had to change it to `#!/bin/zsh` to get it to work

Comment: I guess I don't need the `shopt -s globstar` command either since it doesn't work in zsh. I was told that this doesn't work for mac users since mac has bash 3 and bash 4 is required.

Comment: Yes, it's bash specific. You can write `*/*/*` but that will only work for a specific directory depth. For arbitrary depths, there is `find`.